# VSTS: How to show related tests on a work item in backlog board?

Tags: azure-devops, backlog, test-plan

I've added a *Requirement-based test suites* in *Test Plans* with one test case inside. Obviously, the test case is linked to a *Work Item* in *Backlog*.
The problem is I when I go to backlog board section (/_backlogs/board/Backlog%20items), I cannot see the tests on the related work item: [image]

Now, if I quickly add a test on work item via *Backlog Items* (and not *Test Plans*): [image]

all the previous tests suddenly shows up:

[image: picture #3.]

So, is there anyway to make *Test* section of work items always visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got expected behavior, only when test cases are created from the Kanban board and updated afterwards in Test Manager, the Kanban board shows the correct status. Check the section **Test status in the Kanban board** at website below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/kanban/add-run-update-tests?view=vsts

> Test integration with the Kanban board makes it easy for teams to get
>   started with manual testing and then take advantage of the full
>   testing capabilities in Test Manager later, when required. When test
>   cases are created from the Kanban board and updated afterwards in Test
>   Manager, the Kanban board shows the correct status. However,
>   integration is not optimized to work in the other direction; for
>   example, when users create requirement-based suites with Test Manager
>   instead of in the Kanban board. We intend to make some major
>   performance improvements to this integration in future releases.

Comment: Thanks very much.